# Descargar PDF desde html usando la libreria Html2PDF

Tags: php, html, html2pdf

¿Cómo puedo hacer para descargar por medio de un botón toda mi ventana en HTML a PDF?

Mi archivo es el siguiente: pdfnew.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["generar"])){
    //Incluimos la librería
    require_once 'html2pdf_v4.01/html2pdf.class.php';

    //Recogemos el contenido de la vista
    ob_start();
    require_once 'pdfnew.php';
    $html=ob_get_clean();

    //Pasamos esa vista a PDF

    //Le indicamos el tipo de hoja y la codificación de caracteres
    $mipdf=new HTML2PDF('P','A4','es','true','UTF-8');

    //Escribimos el contenido en el PDF
    $mipdf->writeHTML($html);

    //Generamos el PDF
    $mipdf->Output('PdfGeneradoPHP.pdf');

}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Generar PDF" name="generar"/>
</form>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Generar PDF con PHP</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        #cabecera{
            background:#eee;
            padding:20px;
        }
        h2,h3{
            float:left;
        }
        #cabecera img{
            width: 140px;
            float:right;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="cabecera">
        <h2>Este PDF ha sido generado desde PHP</h2>
        <h3>PHP-PHP
        </h3>
    </div>

    <p>Lista ordenada:
        <ol>
            <li>PHP</li>
            <li>Python</li>
            <li>Ruby</li>
            <li>Java</li>
        </ol>
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Haciéndolo de esa manera solo me genera el PDF en el navegador pero sin contenido me lo genera en blanco, lo ideal seria que el pdf que genere fuese la misma ventana, osea todo lo que esta dentro del archivo pdfnew.php

Como podría hacer eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indica en su [página oficial](https://html2pdf.fr/es/home)

> Esta biblioteca se ha hecho para ayudar en la creación de PDF, no para
>   convertir directamente una página HTML. **Usted no puede utilizar las
>   etiquetas `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`.**

Lo que puedes hacer es tener dos archivos:

**main.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["generar"])){
        //Incluimos la librería
        require_once 'html2pdf_v4.01/html2pdf.class.php';

        //Recogemos el contenido de la vista
        ob_start();
        require_once 'pdfnew.php';
        $html=ob_get_clean();

        //Pasamos esa vista a PDF

        //Le indicamos el tipo de hoja y la codificación de caracteres
        $mipdf=new HTML2PDF('P','A4','es','true','UTF-8');

        //Escribimos el contenido en el PDF
        $mipdf->writeHTML($html);

        //Generamos el PDF
        $mipdf->Output('PdfGeneradoPHP.pdf');

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Generar PDF con PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php require "pdfnew.php";?>

        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Generar PDF" name="generar"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**pdfnew.php**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #cabecera{
        background:#eee;
        padding:20px;
    }
    h2,h3{
        float:left;
    }
    #cabecera img{
        width: 140px;
        float:right;
    }
</style>

<div id="cabecera">
    <h2>Este PDF ha sido generado desde PHP</h2>
    <h3>PHP-PHP
    </h3>
</div>

<p>Lista ordenada:
    <ol>
        <li>PHP</li>
        <li>Python</li>
        <li>Ruby</li>
        <li>Java</li>
    </ol>
</p>
```

Comment: Vlady muchas gracias, me sirvio de mucho tu respuesta, saludos.